# Why is using refs slowing down my React application?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need a few refs of elements to be stored in Redux so that the elements can be focused on.

I have this dropdown:

```
            <BasicSelect
                selectRef={(e) => this.storeRef('make', e) } ... />
```

And here is storeRef:

```
storeRef(list, ref)
{
    if(this.state.refsStored[list]) {
        return;
    } else {
        this.props.storeSelectRef(list, ref);
        var refState = Object.assign({}, this.state.refsStored);
        refState[list] = true;
        this.setState({refsStored: refState});
    }
}
```

From this, it should store the ref once, then simply return after comparing.

However, every time a option in the dropdown of  `<BasicSelect>` is clicked on, the application hangs for a <1s (noticable), and then continues on.

If I change storeRef to the following (obviously the intended result doesn't work):

```
storeRef(list, ref) {
    return;
}
```

The dropdown selection is super fast, and all is good. So how come this comparison `if(this.state.refsStored[list])` is significantly slow?

Comment: What's `this.props.storeSelectRef`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Hanging for an entire second implies something is very, very wrong, like infinite recursion.

Comment: why do you feel the need to store the ref in the state tree? you should only have immutable data in there ideally, dom references are all but immutable. you can keep the ref in the component's instance is way more efficient

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum passes the ref to redux to store in it's state

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon If I kept the ref in the component's instance, how would I trigger `focus()` method of the ref from Redux?

Comment: why would you want to do that? what you are trying to do might very well be a bad user experience. however if you must do that  i would creat a property on the component lets called `lastFocused` that when changed makes the component call the focus method of the ref.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put refs into component state.  Component state should only be used for things that you will need when rendering, and should cause a re-render when you update them.  Save refs directly onto the component instance:

```
<BasicSelect selectRef={selectInstance => this.selectInstance = selectInstance} />
```

I'm also kind of confused what `selectRef` is as a prop, to be honest, but I assume that the `<BasicSelect>` component forwards that ref on to an underlying `<select>`tag?

Anyway, the key point is that you are causing unnecessary re-renders every time because you're calling `setState()`.  Don't do that.

Comment: Almost, <BasicSelect> is a wrapper for a react-select component, and yes it forwards on ref on (the ref has a method called `focus()` which I want to trigger from redux). I'm not putting refs in component state though, I'm passing the ref on to redux. If I was to store the ref in the component, how would I call methods on the ref from elsewhere?

Comment: What exactly is the event that should cause a focus on your input? Storing a ref in the redux store is definitely not the way to go.